# Call handleSubmit in React from another class

Tags: reactjs, function, class, event-handling, mern

So I have a class with a handleSubmit in it and I want to call it from my other file on click of a button.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish that?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Map from './Map';

    render() {
        return(


      <center>
      <a href="" onClick={this.Map.handleSubmit} className="btn btn-success ml-3">Continue  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a>
      </center>

            </div>
      </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So for those who didn't understand Map is the other class I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just render it in my map class instead!

Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If `Map` is a normal class, you'll just need to create a new instance of it first:

```js
let map = new Map();

// Then access like this
onClick={map.handleSubmit}
```

**However**, if the class is a react component, I would highly recommend you don't reuse functions that way, and instead move the function to its own file that both components can import.

```js
function handleSubmit() {
 // Do stuff
}

export default handleSubmit;
```

```js
import handleSubmit from './handleSubmit`;

onClick={handleSubmit}
```